# Adding Contextual Actionbar to file-opening Intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-actionbar

As always, this is a bit difficult to explain so I hope you can all follow.

I have an Activity that allows people to search through their file system for a file they'd like to upload to a server.  What I want, is for when a person clicks a file, that it'll open the file so the user can see if it is the right one/edit it/ect and then click accept to send it or decline to return to the file system search.

Here is what I have so far:

```
File selectedFile = new File(o.getPath());
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(selectedFile);

    Intent i = new Intent(FileChooser.this, FileView.class);
    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(selectedFile), "text/*");
    startActivity(i);
```

I'm able to open the files no problem when I don't try to call FileView.class, of
course.  But then I'm not able to add the menu...I feel like there's something simple I'm missing.

Anyone have any experience doing this?

Comment: "that it'll open the file" -- do you mean "that it'll open the file in some third-party app"?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I'm not sure if it's possible then to actually overlay a menu with that.  Would it be possible to open it in some internal fragment and have the menu on the outer view?

Comment: "I'm not sure if it's possible then to actually overlay a menu with that" -- not really. There are some tricks with services and windows that you can use to float a UI over another app's UI. However, you have no way of knowing if the third-party app is doing something important with that portion of the screen that might interfere with the user's use of that other app. You also have no way of knowing when to get rid of it, if the user elects to take an incoming phone call or something.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the information!